# Running an executable in PATH with the same name as an existing function

Tags: bash, path, function

Sometimes I define a function that shadows an executable and tweaks its arguments or output. So the function has the same name as the executable, and I need a way how to run the executable from the function without calling the function recursively. For example, to automatically run the output of `fossil diff` through `colordiff` and `less -R` I use:

```
function fossil () {
    local EX=$(which fossil)
    if [ -z "$EX" ] ; then
        echo "Unable to find 'fossil' executable." >&2
        return 1
    fi
    if [ -t 1 ] && [ "$1" == "diff" ] ; then
        "$EX" "$@" | colordiff | less -R
        return
    fi
    "$EX" "$@"
}
```

If I'd be sure about the location of the executable, the I could simply type `/usr/bin/fossil`. Bash recognizes that `/` means the command it's an executable, not a function. But since I don't know the exact location, I have to resort to calling `which` and checking the result. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You say, “Bash recognizes that `/` means the command is an executable, not a function.”  Strictly speaking, that’s not true.  In what I believe to be a horrible (and undocumented) design decision, bash allows function names to contain slashes.  The slashes simply cause ``/usr/bin/fossil`` to be a different *string* from `fossil`, so, when you say ``/usr/bin/fossil``, it doesn’t try to run the `fossil` function.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the `command` shell builtin:

```
bash-4.2$ function date() { echo 'at the end of days...'; }

bash-4.2$ date
at the end of days...

bash-4.2$ command date
Mon Jan 21 16:24:33 EET 2013

bash-4.2$ help command
command: command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
    Execute a simple command or display information about commands.

    Runs COMMAND with ARGS suppressing  shell function lookup, or display
    information about the specified COMMANDs.  Can be used to invoke commands
    on disk when a function with the same name exists.
```

Comment: One more options is to escape the command `\date`.

Comment: @jordanm, that works only for aliases. The question was about functions. http://pastebin.com/TgkHQwbb

Answer (score 4):

In scripts, the `#!` line often use `/bin/env bash` to run the bash command based on the path. (It might differ for some utilities). This should work here as well...

(The `command` alternative should also work, but might be dependant on a specific shell) (It works on the Bourne Shell on Solaris, but it actually runs `/bin/command` in that case, which it is a shell built-in on Bash)

Both `/bin/command` and `/bin/env` is listed in SUS, so all compliant implementations should have it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `env`. I was in doubts which answer should I accept, but since the question is about _bash_, its built-in `command` is the best solution.

Comment: On my Linux there is no `command` executable, but `command` also works in `dash`, `ksh` and `zsh`. So I assume it is a shell builtin not only in `bash`. http://pastebin.com/fi3gyNse

Comment: It is not a buildin on Solaris 10 Bourne (That is also available as heirloom-sh). The advantages of an executable with a known path is that it can't be overwritten by a function.

Comment: (The absence of /bin/command might explain why scripts use `/bin/env` after the hash-bang if they do not want to hard-code the shell path)

Answer (score 3):

Gert's answer made me realize that one can use `nice` for the purpose too (I actually had it in one of my scripts without realizing it):

```
$ function date() { echo 'at the end of days...'; }
$ date
at the end of days...
$ nice -n0 date
Mon Jan 21 16:45:21 CET 2013
```

It's less elegant than the other answers, but in some circumstances it could be an useful option.

Comment: You may want to expand this to include a similar alternative: `\`which date\``.

Comment: @EliahKagan The problem with `\`which something\`` is that if there is no `something` executable, unfortunate things can happen. For example if `echo` is missing then `\`which echo\` /bin/rm preciousFile` does something very different than intended.